# Allman indentation in Emacs with C++ in-class-defined member-functions

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation, member-functions

I want Allman-indentation. Thus I tried to set `c-default-style` to each of these: `stroustrup`, `bsd`, `linux`. None of these address the behavior that I see in the below code snippet.

**NOTE**: This question is only relevant for in-class-definition of member functions, which is why other answers on Emacs indentation do not answer this question. As you can see in the snippet, out-of-class definitions are just how I want them to be.
*Further notice*: When I made the code examples inside Emacs and pasted them here, I noticed that `2.)` was formatted like `1.)` and I had to adjust indent inside the markdown editor of stackoverflow to match what I see inside Emacs. What I'm getting at here is that maybe it might be a displaying issue of Emacs rather than an actual indentation issue? Emacs version is 29.1.

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    // 1.)
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
    }

    // 2.)
    void printFoo()
        {
            std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
        }

    // 3.)
    void printFoo() const {
        std::cout << "const foo" << std::endl;
    }

    void printFooNum(int foonum);
};

// 4.)
void Foo::printFooNum(int foonum)
{
    std::cout << "foonum: " << foonum << std::endl;
}
```

`1.)` Is the indentation style that I'm trying to achieve.
`2.)` Is what I get per default with any of the indentation styles that I tried (see above).
`3.)` Is what I get when I leave the brace on the last line, this could be acceptable but it's not Allman (and thus not what I want).
`4.)` Is what I get per default (and what I want) but it's an out-of-class definition. I also want this to work for in-class definition.

I'm also giving you the relevant section of my init.el:

```lisp
(setq c-default-style '((c++-mode . "stroustrup")
                        (c-mode   . "stroustrup"))
      c-basic-offset 4)
(setq evil-shift-width 4)
```